# Complexity of testing if a hypergraph has generalized hypertreewidth $2$

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, treewidth, hypergraphs

A *hypergraph* $H = (V, E)$ consists of a set of vertices $V$ and a set $E$ of *hyperedges*, i.e., subsets of $V$.

The *generalized hypertreewidth* (GHW) parameter is a measure of the cyclicity of a hypergraph which is a variant of its treewidth. Intuitively, it is like a tree decomposition but the width of each node is counted as the number of hyperedges required to cover it. Formally, a *hypertree decomposition* of a hypergraph is defined as a tree $T$ where each node $b \in T$ is labeled by some vertices $V(b) \subseteq V$ and $E(b) \subseteq E$. We that $T$ is a tree decomposition of $H$, namely, we impose the following on the vertex mapping:

- for each hyperedge $e \in E$, there is a node $b \in T$ such that $e \subseteq V(b)$
- for each vertex $v \in V$, the set $\{b \in T \mid v \in V(b)\}$ of the vertices where $b$ occurs is a connected subtree of $T$.

Further, we require the following on the edge mapping:

- for each node $b \in T$, the hyperedges $E(b)$ cover $V(b)$, i.e., $V(b) \subseteq \bigcup_{e \in E(b)} e$.

The *width* of the decomposition $T$ is the maximum, over $b \in T$, of $|E(b)|$. The *GHW* of $H$ is the smallest $k$ such that $H$ has a generalized hypertree decomposition of size $k$.

My question is: **Do we know the complexity of testing, given an input hypergraph $H$, whether it has GHW $\leq 2$?**

It is known that testing whether an input hypergraph has GHW $\leq 3$ is NP-hard [GMS 2007] and having GHW $=1$ is tractable because it is equivalent to being $\alpha$-acyclic as mentioned in [GGS 2014] and this is testable in linear time. I did not find any reference about whether having GHW $\leq 2$ is also tractable, or if it is already hard.

- Georg Gottlob, Zoltán Miklós, and Thomas Schwentick, "[Generalized Hypertree Decompositions: NP-Hardness and Tractable Variants](http://www.dbai.tuwien.ac.at/staff/miklos/ghw.pdf)", 2007
- Georg Gottlob, Gianluigi Greco, and Francesco Scarcello, "[Treewidth and Hypertree Width](https://www.mat.unical.it/~ggreco/files/GottlobGrecoScarcello.pdf)", 2014

Comment: Did you try asking the authors of the paper on hardness for 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A new paper from Wolfgang Fischl, Georg Gottlob, Reinhard Pichler states that it remains hard even for $k = 2$. I still haven't read it however, I am just providing the link:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.01090

Comment: Interesting, thanks a lot for pointing it out! (Haven't read it either though.)

Answer (score 5):

We do not know (to best of my knowledge).